# Optimal wager strategy for high win chance / high odds game

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, odds

In a rigged game of chance where statistically I am expected to win, is there a difference in terms of expected profits, risk, etc - between betting the same amount of money each time (for example using Kelly criterion) vs using variable wager strategies like Martingale or anti-Martingale strategy? For example could I expect to win more when doubling my bet with each win, vs making each bet the same amount? As an example we can say that I am playing a game with 80% chance of winning \$1.3 for each \$1 bet (13:10 odds).

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the answer must be to always use Kelly criterion, which will automatically incorporate partial anti-Martingale. Kelly bet will be calculated based on the available capital that will grow over time and therefore Kelly bet will also grow proportionally to the available capital. Overall, the winnings will be compounded thanks to investing % of the growing capital.